# Pandas Scaling as category not returning expected result when comparing variables

Tags: python, pandas, scale, categories, boolean-logic

I'm doing a few coursera courses and on one of them I have to use pandas `astype` function to categorize some values within a dataframe. As part of the exercise I have to compare grades to see if the `astype` function did indeed put them in order, the given exercise works but the one that I developed later don't. Here are the codes:
**Working Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D'],
                  index=['excellent', 'excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'poor', 'poor'])
df.rename(columns={0: 'Grades'}, inplace=True)
grades = df['Grades'].astype('category',
                         categories=['D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+'],
                         ordered=True)
grades > 'C'
```

**Which returns:**

```
excellent     True
excellent     True
excellent     True
good          True
good          True
good          True
ok            True
ok           False
ok           False
poor         False
poor         False
Name: Grades, dtype: bool
```

**My code**

```
s = pd.Series(['Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'High', 'Low'])
s.astype('category', categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)
s>'Low'
```

**Which returns:**

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

As you can see when he does the comparison of `'High'>'Low'` it returns `'False'`. Am I doing something wrong? Did I lose any concept? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget assign output:

```
print (s > 'Low')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

s = s.astype('category', categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)

print (s > 'Low')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Got it, the function astype just return the value but does no change the function. Thank you so much. Btw, the coursera had the same result as mine that is what got me confused.